# Best approach / practice for handling menu logic subscriptions?

Tags: angular, rxjs

So in my applications i find myself having many different menus that needs to toggle or show / hide components in other corners of my application.

It can be something like a menu selection in a sidebar component, shows / hides a certain component segment, that may or may not contain a nested sub-menu that again shows / hides some other component, based on the item selected.

The method i have been using may be cumbersome, unnecessarily complex, bad practice or just plain wrong. But it works.

And since it works, i have been using it in quite a few projects by now.

The way it works does mean that i have to manually handle unsubscribing, and as i was thinking of how to do it with `RxJs` pipe operators instead, i realized that i have never actually seen how other people solve menu logic. Mainly because i haven't really been looking i guess.

What i usually do is I build a menu service that contains a lot of menu's that the different sections of the application can subscribe to. It is an object of booleans that if true a certain associated component is shown, and if false, the component is hidden using some `*ngIf` conditions.

```
icon_menu_items = {
    section_1: true,
    section_2: false,
    section_3: false,
    section_4: false,
}
icon_menu = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.icon_menu_items);
icon_menu_cast = this.icon_menu.asObservable();
```

And in the same menu service i have a function that i can call from other places, other components in my application:

```
toggle_simple_wind_climate_menu(_type: keyof IconMenuItemsInterface) {
    (Object.keys(this.icon_menu_items) as (keyof typeof this.icon_menu_items)[])
    .forEach((key, index) => {
        this.icon_menu_items[key] = false;
    });
    this.icon_menu_items[_type] = true;
    this.icon_menu.next(this.icon_menu_items);
}
```

The function basically just toggles the boolean state of what is section is selected, and then triggers the `next()` to update the state of the component that needs to be shown / hidden.

[basic illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Aogh.png)

Most sites can have multiple menu selections, and nested menu selections as well.
where selecting items in those menus and nested sub menus, will display different parts of the web application, but it is unclear to me how other sites implement such functionality.

Handling the logic to show / hide or add / remove different parts, forms, tables, cards etc, the way i am doing it, i end up with quite a large menu service as the number of places of toggle show/hide logic grows.

So my question / request is.

How do people usually handle menu logic in Angular, in mid to larger web application?

Basically how people handle multiple layers of show / hide logic in their Angular web apps.

Comment: Common practice is that each menu item is tied to a route, and the route determines which component to load into the corresponding `<router-outlet>` element. Don't know what's the rationale behind your practice. I may be missing something.

Comment: i am not thinking of routes and the router-outlet. But rather in-page / in-route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach: represent the menu (on a logical level) as a tree.

```
export type MenuItem = {
  title: string;
  id: string;
  children: MenuItem[];
  isExpanded: boolean;
  isSelected: boolean;
  hasExpandedChildren: boolean;
  hasSelectedChildren: boolean;
}

export const selectedItemsIds = signal<Set<string>>(new Set());
export const expandedItemsIds = signal<Set<string>>(new Set());

export const MENU: MenuItem[] = [
  {
    title: 'Infrastructure',
    id: 'Infrastructure',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'Devices',
        id: 'Devices',
        children: [],
        isExpanded: false,
        isSelected: false,
        hasExpandedChildren: false,
        hasSelectedChildren: false
      },
      {
        title: 'Models',
        id: 'Models',
        children: [],
        isExpanded: false,
        isSelected: false,
        hasExpandedChildren: false,
        hasSelectedChildren: false
      }
    ],
    isExpanded: false,
    isSelected: false,
    hasExpandedChildren: false,
    hasSelectedChildren: false
  }
] as const;

export const currentMenu = computed(() => {
  const currentMenu = [];
  const selectedIds = selectedItemsIds();
  const expandedIds = expandedItemsIds();

  for (const item of MENU) {
    currentMenu.push(getCurrentItem(item, selectedIds, expandedIds));
  }
});

function getCurrentItem(item: MenuItem, selectedItemsIds: Set<string>, expandedItemsIds: Set<string>): MenuItem {
  return {
    ...item,
    isExpanded: expandedItemsIds.has(item.id),
    isSelected: selectedItemsIds.has(item.id),
    hasSelectedChildren: itemHasSelectedChildren(item, selectedItemsIds),
    hasExpandedChildren: itemHasExpandedChildren(item, expandedItemsIds),
    children: item.children.map(child => getCurrentItem(child, selectedItemsIds, expandedItemsIds)),
  }
}

function itemHasSelectedChildren(item: MenuItem, selectedItemsIds: Set<string>): boolean {
  if (!item.children.length) {
    return false;
  }
  return item.children.some(i => selectedItemsIds.has(i.id) || itemHasSelectedChildren(i, selectedItemsIds));
}

function itemHasExpandedChildren(item: MenuItem, expandedItemsIds: Set<string>): boolean {
  if (!item.children.length) {
    return false;
  }
  return item.children.some(i => expandedItemsIds.has(i.id) || itemHasExpandedChildren(i, expandedItemsIds));
}
```

Then you can control what item is selected or expanded by modifying these sets:

```
export function toggleItemSelected(id: string) {
  const selectedIds = selectedItemsIds();
  if (selectedIds.has(id)) {
    selectedIds.delete(id);
  } else {
    selectedIds.add(id);
  }
  selectedItemsIds.set(new Set(selectedIds)); // new Set() is needed to trigger Signal update
}

export function toggleItemExpanded(id: string) {
  const expandedIds = expandedItemsIds();
  if (expandedIds.has(id)) {
    expandedIds.delete(id);
  } else {
    expandedIds.add(id);
  }
  expandedItemsIds.set(new Set(expandedIds)); // new Set() is needed to trigger Signal update
}
```

And use `currentMenu()` in your template.